# How to understand "one of utility"?

Tags: meaning

Having hard time wrapping my mind around "one of utility".
For example:

> The evaluation criterion used in this discourse is **one of utility**.
>   Does the software serve a purpose?

Any help welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Question Of Usefulness

A utility belt carries tools; a Sports Utility Vehicle is good for recreation or work. A question of utility is usually a question of whether something is a good *practical* tool, as opposed to a question about aesthetics, cost, or such. In this case, it means "a question of usefulness". The word utility could have been followed by a colon, as the question that follows is a summary of the actual evaluation criterion (standard the software is expected to meet).

Comment: Thanks, it clicked now, it's like saying this is the matter of xxx, in similar fashion this is the question of utility, I feel stupid now :-(

Comment: Don't. If you're smart enough that you should have gotten it, then you probably would have on any other day.

Comment: I've received negative point for this question, just curios why?
Perhaps it would be useful to argument negative points given ...